# Scrolling a UIScrollView in a UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

If I have a UIScrollView in a UIScrollview, but I only want the contained scrollview to recieve events and work when the parent scroll view Y Offset is 0.

How does one implement this?

Caveat I didn't mention, using self.ptViewController.collectionView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

Does not help, as the events don't begin passing to the scrollview until the user has released their finger due presumably to the change in FirstResponder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after trying the other suggestions, I found I wasn't able to replicate the fluidity needed to seamlessly scroll as if it were one table.

So long story short, a Scrollview in a scrollview, may be a bad idea if you don't want the user to take their finger off the screen while scrolling between the two.

Thus don't bother, use a UICollectionView and define precisely how each section/header/footer/row cell should be handled.

So what I did was simply add the necessary attribute changes in the Collection Flow Layout, to ensure that all sections and cells were being handled appropriately.

Due to the nature of what I was trying to achieve the flow layout required a lot of math and code to ensure all constraints were handled.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView //Or – scrollViewDidScroll:
{
    if (scrollView==scrollViewA && scrollViewA.contentOffset.y == 0) 
    {
            scrollViewB.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe disabling userInteraction on the child scrollView when the parent is scrolling should also be done ? To avoid conflicts?

Comment: Both of these answers work except for the simple fact that, it means I have to take my finger off the screen and then press it back down again to start scrolling in the other UIScrollView.

Essentially when userInteractionEnabled becomes YES the UI stops working until I take my finger on/off again.

Comment: @DavidvanDugteren You can easily use `– scrollViewDidScroll:` if you don't want to lift your finger.

Comment: @Segev, I don't follow, please explain? I don't see how that helps.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot transfer the first responders between the different scrollviews so you would not have to take your finger off and on again.

However you can do something else:

Once you reach the y=0 point in your parent scrollview, you can then use the touchesMoved event to programatically scroll your contained scrollView.

Basically, you'd do a hit test to make sure the touch is in the contained scrollView, check if the container scrollView contentOffset y position is 0 and then scroll your container scrollView.

Something like:

```
- (void) touchesMoved: (NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
  if (scrollViewContainer.contentOffset.y == 0) 
  {
      if ([self hitTest:[[touches anyObject] locationInView:containedScrollView] withEvent:nil])
      {
          //programatically scroll your contained scrollView
      }
  }
}
```

This code is just a sample to better understand what I mean. You should adjust it to your own needs.

Comment: Ok this makes some sense, but I don't understand how to know how much to scroll the inner scrollview by at this point?

say I call, self.innerscrollview setContentOffset(x,y) animated: NO];

I don't know how I'm supposed to deduce the y value here.

UNless you're saying that I can simply pass the touchesMoved params on to it: self.innerscrollview touchesMoved: touches withEvent: event];

Comment: scrollview does not respond to that selector so you can't use it. you have to do some math. calculate the point of origin (when your inner scrollView becomes active) and then scroll by how much it moved. The touch object in the touches NSSet has locationInView parameter which can help you with this. also check docs at: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITouch_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITouch